# jQuery click event function fires slowly on WordPress but works instantly if used outside of WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm making a side navigation menu for a WordPress theme. It gets toggled into view from the side by changing its class on click with a jQuery function. The problem here is that it takes about a second from when it gets clicked on mobile to actually change the class and reveal the menu. If I try the same thing with the same code outside of WordPress it seems to work perfectly. The menu shows up instantly. I can't figure out what causes it to be so slow on WordPress.

Here's my code:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.nav-burger').on('click', function() {
        $('.nav').toggleClass('open');
    });
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $(".open");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        &&
        container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $('.nav').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

```css
#navigation {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #AA1111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  #navigation {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 270px;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-270px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-270px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-270px);
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  }
  #navigation.open {
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 555;
  }
  #navigation.open~.mask {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 9;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="site-title-container" class="header-elements col-md-3 col-sm-3">
     <p class="nav-burger">Open</p>
     <h3 class="site-title"><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="home">Title</a></h3>
    </div>
<div id="navigation" class="nav">
</div>
```

I initially thought it would be a problem with my function having a delay, but after seeing that there wasn't anything wrong with it, I tried to execute it without WordPress. It worked just as intended, with no delay. Is there any reason why WordPress would cause it to be slow?

EDIT: It's only slow on mobile devices (all of them, not just the worst of smartphones you can imagine). On desktop it works fine. Also, I haven't included all mark-up within the navigation menu so as to not complicate it. I have tested it with the mark-up generated by WordPress and it still works fine outside of WordPress, so that shouldn't be the cause. Here's a live sample of the site for testing: https://played-disassembly.000webhostapp.com/.

EDIT 2: As other have pointed out, it seems to be working well if it's not in Chrome for Android. I tried it out on Firefox and it worked seamlessly. Same thing for Safari on iOS. So the problem seems to be with Chrome.

Comment: if you're comparing it to local code, the local code will always be faster. It's hard to say  without more information, maybe try aliasing the $? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Is your menu slow only on mobile or desktop top as well? Also can you provide a url this makes your site easier to test.

Comment: Do you have exactly the same HTML with and without Wordpress?  If not, is the HTML without Wordpress significantly smaller?

Comment: @Nathaniel Flick it's only slow on mobile devices. It works perfectly if tested with Chrome for desktop. Here is a URL with the site: https://played-disassembly.000webhostapp.com . vlasits I only included the parent div that gets opened here so as to not complicate the mark-up. I've tried testing it out with the exact same HTML generated by WordPress and it still works fine outside of it.

Comment: I don't see any delay. I tried in Safari on an iPhone SE running iOS 11, and in an iPhone X simulator, and your menu seems to work fine... Is there a particular mobile platform that's causing the problem?

Comment: I only tested on Chrome on Android and everywhere I did there was a slight delay between the time you clicked and the time it actually started opening. @MattGibson

Comment: Especially on mobile Safari this is a known issue around how clicks work, there's a 300ms click delay built in: https://developer.telerik.com/featured/300-ms-click-delay-ios-8/. Are you using meta viewport tag in your html?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
There is nothing intrinsic to Wordpress that would cause your client-side code to run slower.  Once the page has loaded into the browser, Wordpress is done.

**Long answer:**

There are several possibilities for what could be causing the performance difference between the local and prod versions of your site.  Here are two of those possibilities:

1. The Wordpress theme is including javascript (either in the form of libraries or in the form of theme-specific js) that is either conflicting with your js (or perhaps just causing performance degredation due to performance problems it has)
2. The prod site has many, many more html nodes which causes performance problems for the combination of your code (which should be pretty performant up to a very large number of nodes) and whatever else is on the site.